# How to add a total distance column in 'flights' dataset? DPLYR, Group_by, Ungroup

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with 'flights' dataset from 'nycflights13' package in R.

I want to add a column which adds the total distance covered by each 'carrier' in 2013.  I got the total distance covered by each carrier and have stored the value in a new variable.
We have 16 carriers so how I bind a row of 16 numbers with a data frame of many more rows.

```
carrier <- flights %>%
group_by(carrier) %>%
select(distance) %>%
summarize(TotalDistance = sum(distance)) %>%
arrange(desc(TotalDistance))
```

How can i add the sum of these carrier distances in a new column in flights dataset?

Thank you for your time and effort here.]

PS. I tried running for loop, but it doesnt work. I am new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mutate` instead:

```
flights %>%
  group_by(carrier) %>%
  mutate(TotalDistance = sum(distance)) %>%
  ungroup()-> carrier
```

We can also use `left_join`.

```
library(nycflights13)
data("flights")
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  left_join(flights %>%
              group_by(carrier) %>%
              select(distance) %>%
              summarize(TotalDistance = sum(distance)) %>%
              arrange(desc(TotalDistance)), by='carrier')-> carrier
```

This will work even if you don't use `arrange` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. This code worked. Can you please explain a bit of this code, i have never used the left_join function before. I know a bit about left join from sql but i dont understand how it applies here. Where is the left table and right table?

As far as iunderstood from your code, 'You went into the flights dataset, then used the left join fucntion'. Everything inside the left_join function is clear to me.

Comment: @SalmanVirani The left table (or data frame) is the table before the ```%>%```. And the part where I summarized the TotalDistance is the right table. Have a look at this, will make things clearer for you: http://lindsaydbrin.github.io/CREATE_R_Workshop/Lesson_-_dplyr_join.html

Comment: I recently had to look somewhere again for joins in R for a refresh, your document came to my mind today. Thanks